# Operation Post-Login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication

I have a blog project in Ruby on Rails.

I want to allow user to leave message without sign in BUT after creating the message I want him to sign in or signup.

The idea is like following, user clicks on "Create Message" then he fill the form of the message, then he clicks on the "Save Message" and if user is not signed in then he redirected to signin/signup form, after signin the system should identify that we have a message for this user, save the message with correct user.id.

I know it's pretty standard technique, if you know some good pattern to do so I would be glad.

Comment: After clicking "create message" button user will be redirected to sign or sign up page? Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: after clicking "create message" user will fill up the form of the message, but after clicking "Save message" user will be redirected to signin/signup form and after then the message will be saved with the user.id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your create action, you should distinguish between 1) user is known and 2) user is not known yet. In the second case, you should store the id of the created message in your session, then redirect to the login/signup page:

```
session[:message] = @message.id
redirect_to new_user_session_path
```

Next step is to interfere with both the create action of the registrations controller (user signed up after your redirect), and with the create action of the sessions controller (user signed in after your redirect)

In both controllers, you can add something like

```
after_filter :assign_pending_message, only: :create
```

with

```
def assign_pending_information_request
  # User succesfully created?
  return unless @user.id

  if session[:message] 
    if Message.exists?(id: session[:message])
      message = Message.find(session[:message])

      message.user = @user
      message.save!
    end

    session.delete(:message)
  end
end
```

If you need more details, just let me know!

Answer (score 1):

Devise doesn't allow `POST` parameters to be sent on authentication, so you need to send message parameters via `GET`, So here user will be redirected to the login page on clicking save message because of the applied filter, Here is a demo

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, :except => [:new]

  def new
    @message = Message.new
  end

  def get_message
    @message = Message.new(params[:message])
    @message.save  
  end
end
```

In the form you explicitly need to mention the URL of `get_message` action otherwise it will take `create` by default, `create` is a post method so it is of no use to us to implement this.

in your routes.rb

```
resources :messages do
  get :get_message, :on => :collection
end
```